# Spring Cloud Kafka Streams binder offset metrics

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

Could somebody please give an example of how to use Spring Cloud Kafka Streams metric `spring.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.offset` for a consumer application?

Edit:

I'd like to add more information after some time spending for the investigation. 
The metrics that I'm looking for have to show me the situation with my stream processing. My binding looks next:

```
@Input(INCOMING_STREAM)
KStream<String, Update> incomingStream();

@Input(INCOMING_MESSAGE)
MessageChannel incomingMessage();
```

And what is quite strange for me I can see different metrics using suggested approaches but only for `INCOMING_MESSAGE` channel. Is there any way to see the metrics from `INCOMING_STREAM`?

Comment: Your question is not clear; please explain further and/or a pointer to some reference.

Comment: yes, probably not very clear (( I have Spring Cloud Kafka application with stream listener. To have more visibility I'd like to see some numbers of items waits for processing. In the official documentation, I found next: `Kafka binder module exposes the following metrics:
spring.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.offset: This metric indicates how many messages have not been yet consumed from a given binder’s topic by a given consumer group.` But for me, it's not very clear how it has to be used.

Comment: Please provide a link to that documentation; I don't see it in the [current docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Elmhurst.SR1/reference/htmlsingle/).

Comment: Gary, you can find it here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/_apache_kafka_binder.html#kafka-metrics. But it looks like there is another one here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/blob/master/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-docs/src/main/asciidoc/overview.adoc#kafka-metrics. Which contains the message I've put previously.

Answer (score 0):

The metrics in Spring Cloud Stream from 2.0 is based on Micrometer (which is the default metrics implementation used in Boot 2.0). You can try to `autowire` a `MeterRegistry` in your application and retrieve the relevant metrics there. See [this test](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/blob/master/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/src/test/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/binder/kafka/KafkaBinderMetricsTest.java) for some pointers. If you don't want to make changes in your application, you can also try setting the `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.applicationMetrics.destination` property. For more details on that,see [this blog](https://spring.io/blog/2018/04/10/announcing-general-availability-of-spring-cloud-stream-elmhurst-release-2-0-0-release#micrometer-support).

Comment: @sobychako, I tried your instruction with Spring Boot 2.4, I configured the ```applicationMetrics.destination```. However, I couldn't find the ```spring.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.offset``` on the destination topics. Could you explain more on this?